# How do I insert a "." into a specific place in a numeric column?

Tags: r, string

I want to insert a "." character after the second digit of every entry in a numeric column.

For instance, I want the numeric value `4440046` to become the string `44.40046`. I have tried several approaches and searched the problem online but I haven't had any luck.

Comment: You will have to give more information about the question.

Comment: hi and welcome to StackOverflow!  I edited your question to make it a little more specific in the hopes of getting an answer - if I made the problem too narrow, please fix my edits.

Comment: Something like `as.numeric(gsub('^([0-9]{2})([0-9]+)$', '\\1\\.\\2', 4440046))`

Comment: @Sotos I think it is a rather different problem as the one you linked. Here, you have a numeric vector, in the linked thread you have a character one. This problem could be solved by very different ways as the linked one. Please consider reopening it :)

Comment: @tmfmnk ahh...yes.Thanks for telling me. Are you thinking math? ;)

Comment: @Sotos yes, I could imagine some nice solutions involving maths :)

Answer (score 1):

One solution that could work for positive numbers may be:

```
x <- c(4440046, 444004600, 4440, 445.2, 40)

x/10^(nchar(trunc(x)) - 2)

[1] 44.40046 44.40046 44.40000 44.52000 40.00000
```

It won't work for single integer positive numbers. However, I'm not sure what should be the output for such cases.

Comment: @Sotos it happens sometimes :D

Answer (score 1):

```
sub("(^[0-9]{2})", "\\1.", as.character(x))
```